# WebWorker to add markers in MapBox FeatureLayer

Tags: javascript, performance, mapbox, web-worker

I am building an app with a MapBox map. I ask to a server a GeoJson file, containing a list of markers, already formatted according to Mongoose schema like this:

```
var poiSchema = new Schema({
  type      :    { type:String, required:true},
  geometry  :    {
                   type        : { type:String},//point
                   coordinates : { type: [Number]} //lng, lat
                 },
  properties:
                 {
                    "marker-color"  : {type:String},
                    "marker-size"   : {type:String},
                    "marker-symbol" : {type:String},
                 }
});
```

In this way I can just take the result and put it on the map with

```
  map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(result_from_server);
```

Anyway I have many markers (around 1000) and it takes a while... 5-6 seconds :(

While it's loading, the GUI is almost stuck, the scroll is very very slow like all the rest. Is there a way to perform the `setGeoJSON` in a WebWorker ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you actually profiled your application, you would find out that what causes your performance problem. It's the DOM operations that are bogging you down. Not the initialization of the marker is the problem but the attaching of marker and shadow img elements to the DOM tree and the resulting paints the browser has to preform.

Sorry to say, you can't preform DOM operations in a javascript worker. A worker thread doesn't have access to the window object so Mapbox/Leaflet can't operate. It won't even load because the first thing the library wants to do is to attach itself, L, to the window object. Also you can't send Leaflet objects from the mainthread to the workerthread because it only accepts values that can be cloned by the structured clone algorithm. That excludes complex objects that have methods, like Leaflet objects.

If you really want to show a large amount of markers you could try and use pure SVG which preforms better or you could take a look at clustering them.

Comment: Thanks for The clarification. I am using the standard Mapbox icons, using the marker-symbol notation. Isn't it a .svg?

Comment: Nope they're images, single PNG file which includes the shadow. Leaflet markers have a separate shadow image.

Comment: So I guess I must use LeafLet icons to use .svg images... it seems MapBox doesn't support them. Or I have to better check.    Could you suggest me a tool to check performance, so I could have seen the issue on png images? Thank you

Comment: actually, I tried to use a .svg icon following this [guide](http://bl.ocks.org/uafrazier/6417e384d22702ac1ebd), but it's even heavier: same loading time, and the map zoom becomes unusable    :(

Comment: What that does is create an img element with a SVG as source. So you're in fact using still using images only with a different source format. What i meant was using an actual SVG path and add it as an overlay. That way you'll have one SVG image (the overlay layer) with multiple paths for markers. Like leaflet's L.CircleMarker for instance. See: http://plnkr.co/edit/jFroSylgY6HXnGZIwbFU?p=preview and inspect that with your DOM inspector. BTW you can profile you're application via the DOM inspector in Chrome, Firefox etc.